# Add two dataframe column in one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe.Now I am trying to add Genotype dataframe cola and colb in first dataframe 1. individualSNPs. I tried append/concat but getting NAN value...

1. individualSNPs

| SNP |
| --- |
| rs02 |
| rs03 |
| rs12 |

2. Genotype

| cola | colb |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |

My result will be like :
IndividualSNPs

| SNP | cola | colb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rs02 | 0 | 1 |
| rs03 | 1 | 1 |
| rs12 | 0 | 0 |

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat) on axis 1:

```py
import pandas as pd

individualSNPs = pd.DataFrame({'SNP': ['rs02', 'rs03', 'rs12']})
Genotype = pd.DataFrame({'cola': [0, 1, 0],
                         'colb': [1, 1, 0]})

out = pd.concat((individualSNPs, Genotype), axis=1)
print(out)
```

`out`:

```
    SNP  cola  colb
0  rs02     0     1
1  rs03     1     1
2  rs12     0     0
```